# Is there an ARIMA model in Spark Scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, arima

How can we do ARIMA modeling in spark scala?

Can we directly import any ARIMA package like regression or classification?

In Spark's ml library, we do not have anything like ARIMA model.

Comment: You might want to check spark-tk https://github.com/trustedanalytics/spark-tk. They do have an ARIMA Model: http://trustedanalytics.github.io/spark-tk/versions/v0.7.3/scala/org/trustedanalytics/sparktk/models/timeseries/arima/ArimaModel.html